# Is it possible to get session ID from cookie?

Tags: laravel, session, authentication

I am learning Laravel from few days and am little confused about how the authentication works in Laravel. Where the sessions are stored?

Comment: I found this in first search in google `PHP Default Session Storage (File System): In PHP, by default session data is stored in files on the server. Each file is named after a cookie that is stored on the client computer. This session cookie (PHPSESSID) presumably survives on the client side until all windows of the browser are closed.`

Comment: It is too broad to discuss here about laravel authentication, can you share exact problem with current code ?

Comment: yes I want to know where is session id? in the cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Getting the Session ID from a cookie?

I wasn't completely sure about what you meant by getting it from a cookie but you could try the code below.

### Imports

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
```

### Code

```
Crypt::decrypt(
  \Request::cookie(
     config('session.cookie')
  )
)
```

## Getting the Session ID

I have not been able to test this but I believe it should work, the 'session()' is a global variable so there's no need for any imports.

### Code

```
$id = session('id');
```

Hope this answered your question, good luck!